# wpf ellipse remove blue border on click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have some ellipses which I am dynamically generating as follows in the cs file when a button is clicked.Problem is when I click on any ellipses the border color becomes blue as shown in the figure. How can I remove the blue background please help.

[image]

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            imgBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/AthenaIsolatedFeatures;component/Widget/Pointers/top.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            imgBrush.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
            ele.Fill = imgBrush;
            lstBox.Items.Clear();
            CircularPanel.AngleRadians((sender as Button).Name);
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) //Assuming 3 images to be created
            {
                ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
                brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/AthenaIsolatedFeatures;component/Widget/SubImages/Target" + (i + 1) + ".png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
                Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse()
                {
                    Name = "Target" + i.ToString(),
                    Height = 70,
                    Width = 70,
                    Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
                    StrokeThickness = 1,

                };

                ellipse.Fill = brush;
                ellipse.MouseLeftButtonDown += Ellipse_MouseLeftButtonDown1;
                lstBox.Items.Add(ellipse);
            }
        }
```

Now when each dynamically generated ellipses are clicked I want to do something

```
 private void Ellipse_MouseLeftButtonDown1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

          //Do something
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the click, instead of

```
ellipse.MouseLeftButtonDown += Ellipse_MouseLeftButtonDown1;
```

you can try

```
e.MouseLeftButtonDown += Ellipse_MouseLeftButtonDown1;
```

And for the background, you can try in the XAML code

```
<Ellipse Width="50" Height="50" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="10" Fill="Transparent"></Ellipse>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Problem is if you see my code I am doing something like Ellipse e=new Ellipse() in the code behind. To remove that blue background I need to apply and call some style to the ellipse. If I say e.Fill=Brushes.Transparent then the content of the ellipse is being removed. I am still unsure how your xaml will help.

Comment: I dont have any xaml for the ellipse. I am dynamically generating it.

Comment: But see my for loop. I want to generate 4 ellipses at the same time and the contents need to change for each of them. If I do it in the xaml I will be able to create only 1.

Comment: You can create an unique eclipse.xaml which only contains exactly the figure as you need, then in your loop you only call it and you're done. I did something similar in a recent project, just let me look for it and give you the example.